# Is it possible to automatically split slide with too long list (slidify, R-Markdown)

Tags: r-markdown, presentation

I create a R Markdown presentation with slidify.

I have a long, numberred list that is too long to be displayed  on one HTML slide. As a result, part of the list is not visible.

If I split this list manually to two slides, numbering order will be incorrect: on the second slide it will start again from 1.

Is it possible to break slide/request automatic split of list in R Markdown / Markdown / html?